Certificate issued by private root CA does not work on iOS
I created a certificate issued by a private root CA so that I can automatically trust the self-signed certificate inside my organization.
The steps that I took lead to a correct handling and automatic trust on Windows, but fail on iOS.
The properties of my generated root certificate are:
Validity: 2024-06-06 thru 2124-05-31
Public Key: RSA, 4096bits
Signature algorithm: SHA-256 with RSA Encryption
Certificate version: 3
Certificate Authority: Yes
Path length: 2
Key Usages: Certificate Signing

The properties of the generated server certificate are:
Common name: <fqdn>
Validity: 2024-06-06 thru 2124-05-31 (100 years)
Subject alt names: <short name>, <fqdn>, <fixed IP address of server>
Public Key: RSA, 4096bits
Signature algorithm: SHA-256 with RSA Encryption
Certificate version: 3
Certificate Authority: No
Path length: 1
Key Usages: Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
Extended Usages: Server Authentication, Client Authentication
Certificate Policies: Certificate Type (2.23.140.1.2.1) [= Domain Validation]

I created all the keys and certificates with OpenSSL and also verified the contents with OpenSSL before issuing them. The steps that I took to install the root certificate on iOS are as follows:

Generate private key
Create root certificate (file ca.pem)
Downloaded ca.pem on iOS device
Open the downloaded file on iOS device
Open Settings on iOS device
Choose Downloaded profile (or similar name, working on device that is set to Dutch language)
Choose Install
Open Settings -> General -> Info
Scroll down and choose Trust certificates
Enable the newly installed profile

When I go to Settings -> General -> VPN and device, I can see the newly installed profile and when I click that profile, I see that the authority is verified.
Then I create a new server certificate with the following steps:

Create a CSR on the server
Sign the server certificate server.pem using the server CSR
Install the certificate server.pem on the server

When I now open a web page on the server on Windows, where I also installed the root certificate, the browsers (both Firefox and Edge) do not warn me about an untrusted certificate and will directly show the requested web page.
On iOS however, Safari  complains that the requested web page is insecure.
Can it be that I have generated certificates with incorrect properties?
As a reference I have also included the commands to generate the keys and certificates using OpenSSL (where pass.txt contains the password used to secure the certificate):
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pass file:pass.txt -out ca-key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096 -aes256
openssl genrsa -aes256 -passout file:pass.txt -out ca-key.pem 4096
openssl rsa -in ca-key.pem -check -noout -passin file:pass.txt
openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -days 36500 -config ca_config.txt -passin file:pass.txt -key ca-key.pem -out ca.pem
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out server.pem -days 36500 -sha256 -extfile server_config.txt -passin file:pass.txt


Try setting the server certificate validity to not more than 397 days. Server certificates validity should not be longer than that , or else they will not be accepted by most browsers.

@not2savvy Based on your comment, I found the following page on Apple support: https://support.apple.com/en-us/102028 that indicates that indeed certificate validity of more than 397 days is no longer possible, but the last bullet on the page indicates "This change will not affect certificates issued from user-added or administrator-added Root CAs.". I believe this is what I am doing, right?

@not2savvy I dug in a little deeper, but it seems there is another restriction that only allows a validity of server certificates of 825 days. So I think I will try that first, and if that does not work, I will try the 397 day validity.

I'm not sure when exactly those restrictions apply or not, and I haven't had time to try it out. So looking forward to you posting an update!

As noted by @not2savvy, the issue was in the validity period of the server certificate. Currently, Apple's Safari does not accept any server certificate with a validity of more than 825 days. For server certificates signed by a global root CA, this is even limited to 397 days.
